# Checking if the Faye server exists before running it for my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, thin, faye

In relation to a previous question of mine found here:

[Autorun the Faye server when I start the Rails server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430437/autorun-the-faye-server-when-i-start-the-rails-server)

I am now running the Faye server whenever I start Rails. However, this means it is trying to run the Faye server when I run the Rails server, the Rails console, or anything else Rails related.

Is there a way to check if the Faye server is already running? And if it is, not attempt to run a new one? Or maybe this isn't the best approach, I welcome all ideas and tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DaemonController](https://github.com/FooBarWidget/daemon_controller) library. It will enable you to auto-start services with your Rails app, starting them if they aren't already started.