# Running Thin Faye instance separate from nginx+Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, thin, faye

I have several Rails apps running by Passenger+nginx 1.2.

I need to add some Comet features to one of them, but i don't want to add any `tcp_module` and rebuild nginx, i just need separate Faye+Thin instance running on subdomain of my app http://faye.myapp.com:9292 (on the same Ubuntu machine) and listening clients directly.

Is there elegant solution of that problem?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430437/autorun-the-faye-server-when-i-start-the-rails-server